# Run multiple deployment pipelines together

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

A single deployment at my organization might involve running half a dozen different pipelines.

Some of these pipelines are classic "Release" pipelines.  Some of these are modern yaml pipelines.

Sometimes these pipelines need to run sequentially.  Sometimes they can run in parallel.

Is there any way in Azure DevOps (Server 2020) that I can group these together so that I can deploy the whole set with one command?

Comment: Do you mean 1) you have some **build** pipelines(using classic and yaml) 2) you want to run them like pipeline set with one command ?

Comment: You could use a REST api to trigger a bunch of pipelines altogether. Look an article example. https://blog.geralexgr.com/cloud/trigger-azure-devops-build-pipelines-using-rest-api .  You could use a simple powershell script to trigger more than one pipeline all at the same time with POST commands.